# Setting mime type for excel document

Tags: excel, content-type, mime

MS Excel has the following observed MIME types:

- `application/vnd.ms-excel` (official)
- `application/msexcel`
- `application/x-msexcel`
- `application/x-ms-excel`
- `application/x-excel`
- `application/x-dos_ms_excel`
- `application/xls`
- `application/x-xls`
- `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` (xlsx)

Is there any one type that would work for all versions? If not, do we need to set `response.setContentType()` with each one of these mime types individually?

Also, we use file streaming in our application to display document (not just excel - any type of document). In doing so, how can we retain the filename if the user opts to save the file - currently, the name of the servlet that renders the file appears as the default name.

Comment: More generally, the best way to find out what MS themselves think is the correct type is to find a box with the latest version installed and look at `HKCR/.xls` 's `Content Type` value in the registry.

Comment: "application/vnd.ms-office" is another mime type for XLS files.

Comment: `application/vnd-xls` also works for `.xls` files.

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4212908/465053) post for complete list of MIME types and related excel file extensions.

Comment: The standard excel MIME type is:-   application/vnd.ms-excel

Answer (score 405, accepted):

I believe the standard [MIME type for Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/vsofficedeveloper/office-2007-file-format-mime-types-for-http-content-streaming-2) files is `application/vnd.ms-excel`.

Regarding the name of the document, you should set the following header in the response:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="name_of_excel_file.xls"');
```

Comment: what is the difference between application/msexcel and application/vnd.ms-excel?

Comment: If you're wanting to display the document within the browser (if supported) then Content-Disposition needs to be 'inline'. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395151/content-dispositionwhat-are-the-differences-between-inline-and-attachment

Comment: You should avoid using Content-Disposition in HTTP, it has security considerations. Content-Disposition is only for email. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012437 for more info.

Comment: Note that for OpenXML Excel XLSX file format a different Mime type is defined, see the full list at the link provided.

Comment: @DzmitryLazerka what is the "secure" alternative to content-disposition? Following your link, then the link in that answer, then the link in that document, gets us to here: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266#section-4.3. As far as I can tell, the security concern is just involving filenames provided by users--if they contain non-latin characters, or characters that are invalid on some OS. All the major browsers have safeguards against these concerns. Windows and Mac also set a flag on a file indicating that it came from the internet, popping up a warning when you try to open it.

Comment: @Kip Not only bad characters, but also Javascript, there was a link in that question comments on content-disposition hacking.

Comment: Secure alternative is to make URL to download that ends on desired filename, I believe.

Answer (score 223):

Waking up an old thread here I see, but I felt the urge to add the "new" .xlsx format.

According to http://filext.com/file-extension/XLSX the extension for .xlsx is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`. It might be a good idea to include it when checking for mime types!

Comment: This was what I was looking for thanks, needed to support the latest format as well as the previous.

Answer (score 68):

For **.xls** use the following content-type

```
application/vnd.ms-excel
```

For **Excel 2007** version and above **.xlsx** files format

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

Answer (score 9):

I was setting MIME type from .NET code as below -

```
File(generatedFileName, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
```

My application generates excel using OpenXML SDK. This MIME type worked -

```
vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) to generate .xlsx (OpenXML format based) excel file. For sending this excel file as attachment in email I use the following MIME type and it works fine with EPPlus generated file and opens properly in ms-outlook mail client preview.

```
string mimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
System.Net.Mime.ContentType contentType = null;
if (mimeType?.Length > 0)
{
    contentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(mimeType);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is still stumbling with this after using all of the possible MIME types listed in the question:

I have found that iMacs tend to also throw a MIME type of "text/xls" for XLS Excel files, hope this helps.