# What are the security considerations of using the content-dispositon HTTP header?

Tags: security, http, http-headers, content-disposition

In response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012437/uses-of-content-disposition-in-an-http-response-header/1012461#1012461), what are the security considerations when using the content-disposition HTTP header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uh... They're spelled out in [RFC 2183](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt), linked to from the answer *you* link to!

> 5. Security Considerations
>
>    There are security issues involved any time users exchange data.
>      While these are not to be minimized, neither does this memo change
>      the status quo in that regard, except in one instance.
>
>    Since this memo provides a way for the sender to suggest a filename,
>      a receiving MUA must take care that the sender's suggested filename
>      does not represent a hazard. Using UNIX as an example, some hazards
>      would be:
>
>    - Creating startup files (e.g., ".login").
>    - Creating or overwriting system files (e.g., "/etc/passwd").
>    - Overwriting any existing file.
>    - Placing executable files into any command search path
>        (e.g., "~/bin/more").
>    - Sending the file to a pipe (e.g., "| sh").
>
>    In general, the receiving MUA should not name or place the file such
>      that it will get interpreted or executed without the user explicitly
>      initiating the action.
>
>    It is very important to note that this is not an exhaustive list; it
>      is intended as a small set of examples only.  Implementors must be
>      alert to the potential hazards on their target systems.