# Download a file from a web server in ASP.Net 4.0 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, download

I am hosting files on my web server and I want the end user to be able to download a copy of this file on their machine to open and view.  I currently have a list that is populated through a foreach loop and each iteration through the loop is a @Html.ActionLink("blahblahblah").  Is there a way to download the file on the action link click?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How has the current behavior not met your expectations?

Answer (score 3):

Clicking a link **does** download the file...  IF the file is HTML, the browser downloads it and shows it in the browser; if it's something else (like an EXE) then the browser downloads it to the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `Html.ActionLink`, use `Url.Content` with the (app-relative) path to the file you want them to download.  `ActionLink` is for generating hrefs that point to actions on a controller, not raw files in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Are those files open to public? Is there a restriction etc? Why not just have plain static links to those files.

Action link only creates links that will be routed to a specific Controller and Action.

If you need to protect those files then you can add code in the appropriate Action of the controller. This action would read bytes from the file and the dump it in the response. You would have to add Headers to the browser will recognize the mime type and display the download dialog or render the content accordingly.

Check this item
[Returning a file to View/Download in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-mvc)