# Downloading file from my project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller with a method for downloading file. Without code, all I need is to go to this link:

```
http://localhost:1186/Content/MyFolder/file1.exe
```

and the file gets downloaded.

I tried to do this with code like this:

```
Response.Redirect(Server.MapPath("~\\Content\\MyFolder\\file1.exe"));
```

But the breakpoint passes through this line and nothing happens. I think the problem is I'm using Server.MapPath, but how else would I do this?

Comment: Server.MapPath return the physical path of the resource, try Response.Redirect("~\\Content\\MyFolder\\file1.exe");

Comment: This related SO question about downloading files with MVC may be helpful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this

create an action

```
public ActionResult RedirectToDownload()
{
    return View();
}
```

and then on the view with JavaScript on load redirect to your URL

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.navigate("~/Content/MyFolder/file1.exe");
});
```

you might also use this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return Redirect("~/Content/MyFolder/file1.exe");
}
```

Comment: I don't see the point of having the controller send the user to a view which redirects the user again. It's the controller's primary job to perform the redirections.

Comment: you still need a view unless you are dowloading the file directly from the action

Comment: @Despertar http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/01/response-redirect-and-asp-net-mvc-do-not-mix.aspx

Comment: window.navigate don't works in all the browsers(ex. firefox) as well the "~" symbol.

Comment: @Mark have not seen a browser that would not recognize ~

Comment: Well I'm not whether any browser would recognize "~", when you try window.location = "~/Content/MyFolder/file1.exe"

Comment: Well I'm stopping here! May be you should go and check before posting comments.