# Calling Save dialog box from javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a javascript function from which I need to call a controller action to return the filestream to the UI .
I am not getting the open,save and save as dialog box.
In the cshtml file I have following function:DownloadFile

```
var selectUrl = '@Url.Action("Download", "Controller")' + "/" + filedetails; 
$.post(selectUrl);
```

and in the controller I have the following code:

```
public ActionResult Download(string id)
return File(downloadStream, "application/octet-stream",fileName);
```

Please let me know is this the correct way of calling.

Comment: You dont see the dialog box, but what exactly happens when you call that javascript function.------------ Please edit your post and correctly use code tag.

Comment: On click of the button I want to call the ActionResult which returns File(downloadStream, "application/octet-stream",fileName);  so that the user can see the open dialog box.

Comment: I understand what you want, I am asking what is happening now when you click the button? Nothing happens?

Comment: Nothing is happening ,its just executing and nothing is displayed in UI

Comment: Use `var selectUrl = '@Url.Action("Download", "Controller", new {id=filedetails})'` and tell me if it works. Apparently, you are not going to the correct url. Put a debug pointer in your Download Action to see if your request reach there.

Comment: Ya I am able to hit the action but dont know why its not returning the dialog box.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13218/discussion-between-user1400915-and-mohayemin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way :ActionResult

```
 public ActionResult Download(string id) 
    {
          var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
                    {

                        FileName = "imagefilename",
                        Inline = false,
                    };
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
        string contentType = "application/octet-stream";
          // you are downloadStream
        return File(downloadStream, contentType);
    }
```

[link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-mvc)