# Asp.net Web API - How to set the filename for a custom CSV Media Type Formatter

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I have successfully implemented a Csv Media Type Formatter in my ASP.Net Web API project.  I am able to get results back in Csv format.  However the resulting filename is "parts" without an extension.

Ideally, I want to be able to set this filename in the controller, but being able to add the extension globally would be a minimum.

**Below are the examples I have found**

Override OnGetResponseHeaders - I don't see that as an option in the current version.
http://forums.asp.net/t/1782973.aspx/1?Setting+response+and+content+headers+esp+ContentDisposition+inside+a+MediaTypeFormatter

According to that article this should work

```
public override IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> OnGetResponseHeaders(Type objectType, string mediaType, HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
{
       return new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=testing.csv") };
}
```

However Visual Studio says "There is no suitable method for override" and won't compile when I add that to my custom Csv Formatter.

Return HttpMessageResponse from controller - [How to set downloading file name in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145390/how-to-set-downloading-file-name-in-asp-net-mvc-web-api)
However this appears to just be pushing existing server files, which would take the Csv serialization out of the mix.  Below is an attempt to make this approach work:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();

    if (id == "test")
    {
        var data = GetTestData();
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        response.Content = new StreamContent(data);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "testorama.csv";
        return response;
    }

    return null;
}
```

The issue here is that new StreamContent() is expecting a stream - is there a way to get the current stream that Custom Csv Formatter created?

Bottom line, how can I set the filename for a resultset that is first serialized to Csv format?

**Solution**

Thanks Claudio - that got me going in the right direction.  A couple changes from what you posted:

1. I was deriving from BufferedMediaTypeFormatter for my custom Csv
   Formatter and to use SetDefaultContentHeaders I had to instead
   derive from MediaTypeFormatter.
2. SetDefaultContentHeaders accepts the mediaType parameter with a type of
       MediaTypeHeaderValue and not string.

Here is the final code:

```
public override void SetDefaultContentHeaders(Type type, HttpContentHeaders headers, MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType)
{
    base.SetDefaultContentHeaders(type, headers, mediaType);
    headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=testorama.csv");
}
```

Comment: Why did you need to inherit `MediaTypeFormatter` instead of the `BufferedMediaTypeFormatter`, I think both should work.

Comment: @Tomas, Looks like you are right - SetDefaultContentHeaders is also available with BufferedMediaTypeFormatter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Override the method `SetDefaultContentHeaders` on your MediaTypeFormatter

```
public override void SetDefaultContentHeaders(
    Type type, HttpContentHeaders headers, string mediaType)
{
    base.SetDefaultContentHeaders(type, headers, mediaType);
    headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=yourname.csv");
}
```

Comment: Marked as the solution, but see my original post for a couple changes that I made.

Comment: Do you know a way to access the object you want to return? That is, I have an object and I want to base the filename on that object. In `SetDefaultContentHeaders` I don't have access to the object I' returning.

Comment: @TomasJansson: I'm not sure about the execution order an can't test it now but if the `WriteToStream` runs before than `SetDefaultContentHeaders` you may be able to assign the object on `WriteToStream` to a property so you can access the object later.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi, I already tried that and it didn't work. If you're interested I asked the question and got an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563571/how-to-access-the-underlying-object-in-setdefaultcontentheaders

Comment: I had to change `string mediaType` to `MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType` Worked great after that.

Comment: Even safer:
``headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "yourname.csv" };``

Answer (score 7):

In order to provide a custom name based on the data (at least in Web API 2), you will want to override GetPerRequestFormatterInstance. From there you can get access to the HttpRequestMessage.

```
private string FileName { get; set; }

public override void SetDefaultContentHeaders(Type type, HttpContentHeaders headers, MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType)
{
    base.SetDefaultContentHeaders(type, headers, mediaType);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileName))
        headers.Add("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", FileName));
}

public override MediaTypeFormatter GetPerRequestFormatterInstance(Type type, HttpRequestMessage request, MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType)
{
    // We aren't setting the name, so just return the current instance.
    if (!request.Properties.ContainsKey("filename")) return this;

    var formatter = new CsvFormatter();
    var fileName = request.Properties["filename"] as string;
    formatter.FileName = string.Format("{0}.csv", fileName);
    return formatter;
}
```

Then, in your controller action, you can set the filename like this...

```
if (!Request.Properties.ContainsKey("filename"))
    Request.Properties.Add("filename", "MyFile.{ext}");
```

I use {ext} in case I add additional formatters that require a filename. In theory, only the extension should have to change to support the other formats.

Comment: +1 for the GetPerRequestFormatterInstcance and request property trick. though, in my implementation, I don't need recreate an instance of the formatter when affecting the file name: I simply set the property, then return "this":       

`if (!request.Properties.ContainsKey("OutputFilename")) 
    return this;
this.FileName = request.Properties["OutputFilename"] as string;
return this;`

Comment: Does Web.API create an instance of the formater for every request, or it reuses a single instance? Because your solution might face some concurrency problems...

Comment: The FileName property is on the request instance. This is a different object than the one used to create that instance. As long as you follow the code and set the FileName property of the request instance, you should be fine.