# How to access the underlying object in SetDefaultContentHeaders?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a web api where I return a object. When I use the accept header "image/jpg" i want the image representation of that object, but I want to set the file name based on the object I'm returning. I have implemented a `BufferedMediaTypeFormatter` and thought I should do this in the method `SetDefaultContentHeaders` like such:

```
public override void SetDefaultContentHeaders(Type type, HttpContentHeaders headers, MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType)
{
    base.SetDefaultContentHeaders(type, headers, mediaType);
    var myObject = // How do I get this from the response?
    var contentDispositionHeader = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") 
        { FileName = myObject.FileName };
    headers.ContentDisposition = contentDispositionHeader;
}
```

So the problem is how do I get the underlying object when I am in the `SetDefaultContentHeaders`? I was able to do it in the beta by reading it from the `HttpResponseMessage` that was passed in to the method, but that has been removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't get the object instance there.

The only place in the formatter where you can access the object is the `WriteToStreamAsync`, and by that time you can't modify the headers anymore as they are already sent.

You have two options, either save the filename in the `request.Properties` in your controller and retrieve in the formatter by overriding `GetPerRequestFormatterInstance` (because it runs before `SetDefaultContentHeaders`). Then you can use this value in `SetDefaultContentHeaders`

```
//Controller
public Url Get(int id)
        {
            Request.Properties.Add("name", _repo.Get(id).Name);
            return _repo.Get(id);
}

//Formatter
        public override MediaTypeFormatter GetPerRequestFormatterInstance(Type type, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType)
        {
            //here save the request.Properties["name"] to some local field which you can use later
            return base.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance(type, request, mediaType);
        }
```

Another is to use a delegating handler at the end of the pipeline:
I.e. (of course you have filter out when you want to deserialize and so on):

```
public class RenameHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(t =>
            {
                var msg = t.Result;
                var myobj = msg.Content.ReadAsAsync<IMobi>().Result;
                msg.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = myobj.Name + ".mobi";

                return msg;
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you return a new instance from GetPerRequestFormatterInstance or you will have threading issues (the single default instance will be used for all requests).