# Redirect to new page and download file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am building a website in MVC. At the moment i need to return to a view and download a file.

This return downloads the file:

```
return "http://formvalue.co.za/download/" + filename + ".xlsx";
```

And this return will direct me to my view:

```
return "Complete";
```

The views name is complete.

I can only have one return but i need both actions preformed?

Is there some way to do them both in one return?

Please if you need more info just ask, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Do you *really* need to track whether the file was downloaded or not? Personally, I would re-direct the user to a "Thank you for downloading" page rather than a "Complete" page and trigger the download via an AJAX request. The user will already get a "Download Complete" notification via the browser so you probably don't need to do one yourself.

Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-mvc) of how to download a file using MVC.