# Populating the data attribute of an object tag in Chrome with an ASP.NET MVC action that serves a PDF file result

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

I have a FileResult action that returns a PDF. I want to embed this PDF in an object tag. When I insert the action into the data attribute of the object tag, like below, no PDF is retrieved or shown in Chrome. (The PDF is shown in Firefox with the Adobe plugin - I don't care about IE.)

```
<object data="@Url.Action("GetPDF", "PDFCreation", new {id= Model.DocumentId})" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

It all works otherwise - the object tag works with a direct link to a PDF on the file system (e.g., data="~/Content/test.pdf"), and the Action above, if hard-pasted into the location bar, downloads the PDF.

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: I think that is a plugin issue, if i try it in IE9, nothing happens.  If it do it in Chrome, it complains about a pdf plugin not loading.  If i try it in firefox, all works ok.

Comment: You're right - does work in Firefox (with the Adobe plugin), but not in Chrome (of course IE is a lost cause in all of this, and I'm just using pdf.js iframe there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it via this answer: [Returning a file to View/Download in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-mvc)

Had to append a content disposition header, and set the "Inline" value of the content disposition to true.

```
var doc = ...
var contentDisposition = new ContentDisposition
{
    FileName = doc.FileName,
    Inline = true
};

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.ToString());

return File(doc.Path, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Slicksim! Very much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks a ton, had been looking for awhile as to why a pdf would not load in Chrome, but would for IE, changing that one bool fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get IE to display a Pdf that was thrown back using a FileContentResult and the following object tag

```
<object>
    <embed src="@Url.Action("GetPDF", "PDFCreation", new {id= Model.DocumentId})" type="application/pdf"></embed>
</object>
```

Might be worth a try

Comment: Still won't work for Chrome. (I believe IE9 ignores the object tag and falls back to whatever is inside the object tag.)