# MVC - display all images in single page as gallery from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I stored few images in sql server database in binary format and then retrieved them back and im able display as image but my requirement is that i should display all the images as gallery from database but im able to display only the 1st image as gallery...

my problem is in my controller code as in the forloop its returning file for the first loop itself and view is displayed

Controller

```
public ActionResult DislpayAllImage()
{
    DataSet dsa = new DataSet();
    dsa = objImage.getAllImages();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = dsa.Tables[0];
    if (dt != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Byte[] image = (Byte[])dt.Rows[i]["UsImage"];
            return File(image, "image/jpg");
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

View

```
@foreach( var image in ViewData.Images )
{
    <img src="@Url.Action("DislpayAllImage", "Home",new { id = image.ImageID })" />
}
```

Comment: displaying more than 1 image in single page from datatbase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a notion, not entire code is properly implemented and tested.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   ViewData["count"]=..count the number of rows which have binary image data
}
```

Then in your view get the view data and loop through

```
@for(int i=0;i<=ViewData["count"];i++)
{
   <img src="@Url.Action("DislpayAllImage", "Home",new { id = i})" />
}
```

Then in your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
        DataSet dsa = new DataSet();

        dsa = objImage.getUserImage(id);
        Byte[] imagedata = (Byte[])dsa.Tables[0].Columns["MyImage"];
        return File(imagedata, "image/jpg");

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: yes, but the problem here is return File(imagedata, "image/jpg");, is just returning image here, the view is not getting called

Comment: What do you see in your view ?

Comment: my view is not even being called

Comment: im getting compilation error in my view near forloop as 'Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'object''

Comment: @colorsbright the idea is to get that `ViewData["count"]` to the view and loop throught to get images

Comment: thnku, ur idea worked great for me...i changed the view like this...@for(int i=1;i<=Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["count"]);i++)
{
   <img src="@Url.Action("dp", "Home",new { id = i})" />
}

Comment: can we make alignmnet for this?

Comment: Yes you can, better give a try at first and if you dont get it then you can search for it

Comment: how about pdf files,im storing few pdf files also along with images, so i want that pdf files to be downloaded automatically?

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5830215/1551730) post and entire thread as well

Comment: what value does the variable document holds in that post, binary value of pdf?? also im not getting document.FileName,document.Data, document.ContentType after typing document?

Answer (score 1):

MVC controller can return only once! Try it:

```
ViewData.Images = new List<byte[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   dt.Rows.Add((Byte[])dt.Rows[i]["UsImage"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you can't do `return File(image, "image/jpg");` in your for loop as it will return the first image as you wrote in your explanation.

So instead of returning in the for loop how about you collect the images and return the list?

```
List<File> fileList = new List<File>();
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Byte[] image = (Byte[])dt.Rows[i]["UsImage"];
            fileList.Add(File(image, "image/jpg"));
        }
```

and then return your view with the images as a parameter.

```
return View(fileList);
```

Comment: nice but getting error inthis line fileList.Add(Image(image, "image/jpg"));...note my model name is Image and i decalred list in this way  List<Image> fileList = new List<Image>();

Comment: Image is a type but used like a variable?

Comment: is it possbile to hold images in list??

Comment: What is the return type of this? `File(image, "image/jpg")`

Comment: this is returning me image, and Image is my model name

Comment: @colorsbright then what you want to do is 
`List<Image> imageList = new List<Image>();`
`imageList.Add(File(image, "image/jpg"));`

Comment: im not getting the keyword File

Comment: in the code you posted you do `return File(image, "image/jpg");`
if what you say in the comments is correct you have a method called **File** that returns **Image**.

Comment: imageList.Add(File(image, "image/jpg"));..here im getting the error as 'the best overload match for....has some invalid arguments..ru sure that list can hold images??

Comment: If Image is a class then, YES!

Comment: my Image is a class then??

Comment: Let's do this again... What is the return type of the method `File(image, "image/jpg")`? if that is an `Image` then you should have no problem putting said `Image` in a `List<Image>`

Comment: but my issue is in this line  imageList.Add(File(image, "image/jpg"));??

Comment: @colorsbright, it's very difficult to help you if you don't answer any questions. I don't have all of your code so I don't know what you are trying to do. I can only make assumptions and ask you for more info which you don't give me.

Comment: thnku for sparing ur valuable time