# Download functionality MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, download

I have created a web api which connects users to dropbox via OAuth. I am using an API to interact with Dropbox, which works locally as I would like, however when I deploy the API to my Azure server, I am unable to download. I had anticipated this would happen, as my API is currently hard codded to a path on my machine. 
Here is the method I am using:
NOTE: *I call this method through an ActionResult, as part of the MVC portion of my project*

```
public FileSystemInfo DownloadFile(string root, string path)
        {
            var uri = new Uri(new Uri(DropboxRestApi.ApiContentServer),
                String.Format("files?root={0}&path={1}",
                root, UpperCaseUrlEncode(path)));

            var oauth = new OAuth();
            var requestUri = oauth.SignRequest(uri, _consumerKey, _consumerSecret, _accessToken);

            var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
            var response = request.GetResponse();

            var metadata = response.Headers["x-dropbox-metadata"];
            var file = ParseJson<FileSystemInfo>(metadata);

            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;
                do
                {
                    bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);                    
                    memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                } while (bytesRead > 0);

                file.Data = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }                                    
            return file;                                    
        }
```

This is where I call the method in my action result.

```
var file = api.DownloadFile("dropbox", "Public/downloadThis.jpg");
                    path = file.Path;
                    file.Save(@"....\Desktop\DemoTest\Downloads\downloadThis.jpg"); --- this is the problem & *Save* is a stream writer
```

Is there a procedure to follow when downloading files from a server on a browser?

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5830215

Answer (score 0):

public ActionResult download(Models.downloadModel dowld, Models.LoggerView log)
        {

```
        string TC_ID = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
        string filename = TC_ID+"_LoggerData" + ".zip";
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/files/" + filename));
        Response.End();
```

}