# download a file from a folder using Download link in mvc3

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf, download

I'm building a mvc3 application which uses a SQL Server Database with a table named Field.
this table has many columns.one of it's columns is File9Terme with string value and store a PDF file path that stores in a folder named BOOKS.
I build a upload file for this. but now I want to build a download link for each PDF file. here is my code:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public FileResult Download(int id)
 {
    var document = db.Fields.First(f => f.FieldId == id);
    var filename = document.File9Terme;
    return File(filename, document.GetType().ToString());
 }
```

and here is my Index view:

```
<td>
<%= Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", "FieldController", new { id=item.FieldId })%>
</td>
```

where is the problem?
thanks for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning a file to View/Download in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a link, it will send a GET request. So remove `[HttpPost]`.

Secondly, if the Download action method is in the FieldController, simply provide "Field" in your ActionLink and not "FieldController"

```
<td>
<%= Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", "Field", new { id=item.FieldId })%>
</td>
```