# Return byte array from MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, arrays

I am trying to return a byte array from my MVC project controller to an html view. So far I haven't had any luck with trying to use `FileStreamResult`, due to Type `System.Web.Mvc.FileStreamResult` cannot be serialized. How can I return the byte array from my `Controller` to a `View` so that I can download a file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning a file to View/Download in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-mvc)

Comment: Try this: [HttpGet]
        public FilePathResult DownloadTemplate()
        {
            return this.File(Path.Combine(this.excelTemplateFolder, this.excelTemplateFileName), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        }