# ASP.NET MVC 4, C#: how to Download File

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, httppostedfilebase

I have uploaded a file into my database previously, now I want to download that file from my database.

Can anyone show me how? I am new to C# and ASP.NET MVC.

**Controller :**

```
public ActionResult Details(string id = null)
{
        Assignment assignment = db.Assignments.Find(id);

        if (assignment == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(assignment);
}
```

**Model:**

```
public string AssignmentID { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> SubmissionDate { get; set; }
public string Status { get; set; }
[Range(0,100, ErrorMessage="Only Value between 0-100 is accepted.")]
public Nullable<decimal> Mark { get; set; }
public string Comments { get; set; }
public byte[] FileLocation { get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
<div class="display-label">
    <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FileLocation) %>
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FileLocation) %>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-mvc

Comment: there is nothing wrong with my answer..<%: Url.Action("Details","// your controller name//", new{ id = item.ID }) %>..is mazor part of answer.....thankzz..@WeakestInCoding....

Comment: @WeakestInCoding....worked????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have the a `Stream` or `byte[]` or a path of a file, you can use the `File()` method that comes from `Controller` base class, and respond this file as an `ActionResult`, for sample:

```
public ActionResult Details(string id = null)
{
     Assignment assignment = db.Assignments.Find(id);

     if (assignment == null)
     {
         return HttpNotFound();
     }

     return File(assigment.FileLocation, "content/type", "fileName.extension");
}
```

Remember to get the right `content-type` and add a `fileName` with the correct extension.

Answer (score 1):

Based on how you're retrieving the file from your database, you can use ASP.NET MVC's `File()` helper method to return your file to the client.

This [blog article](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/8/uploading_and_returning_files) has a very good description of how to use the `File()` helper and what ends up getting returned.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ya this Helped
 Thanks a million =)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `@url.action` to display images on view :

View :

```
<%: Url.Action("ImageDetails","// your controller name//", new{ id = item.ID }) %>
```

and in your action:

```
public ActionResult ImageDetails(string id = null)
{
     Assignment assignment = db.Assignments.Find(id);

     return File(assignment.FileLocation, "content/type", "file.extension");
}
```

Remember to get the right `content-type` and add file correct `extension` otherwise file will not be rendered properly in view.

If you want only to download file not display then :-

```
public ActionResult Details(string id = null)
{
     Assignment assignment = db.Assignments.Find(id);

     return File(assignment.FileLocation, "content/type", "file.extension");
}
```

Comment: What is it? Copied my awnser with and change it worst solution? A File cannot be rendred in View!

Comment: @FelipeOriani....just try above code ..with url.action file will render on view...

Comment: If it was not An Image, will it still display? i mean Docx or txt

Comment: @WeakestInCoding...yes anything can be displayed because while returning file in controller you are specifying content type and file extension also....

Comment: Erm i not sure how to Set it,
<%: Url.Action("Details","Assignment", new{ id = Model.AssignmentID}) %> Did i set wrong

Comment: @WeakestInCoding...its correct..then pdf or txt is rendering or not??

Comment: file.extension    
what should I do If I want to download into more different format file

Comment: @WeakestInCoding..then store file extension values in database when you are storing files in database and  retrieve file extenstion also  while you are retrieving file from database..