# How to download file with MVC4/Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a MVC-application. And I want to download a pdf.

This is a part of my view:

```html
<p>
    <span class="label">Information:</span>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadFile")) { <input type="submit" value="Download"/> }
</p>
```

And this is a part of my controller:

```c#
private string FDir_AppData = "~/App_Data/";

public ActionResult DownloadFile()
{
    var sDocument = Server.MapPath(FDir_AppData + "MyFile.pdf");

    if (!sDocument.StartsWith(FDir_AppData))
    {
        // Ensure that we are serving file only inside the App_Data folder
        // and block requests outside like "../web.config"
        throw new HttpException(403, "Forbidden");
    }

    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(sDocument))
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return File(sDocument, "application/pdf", Server.UrlEncode(sDocument));
}
```

How can I download the specific file?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning a file to View/Download in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-mvc)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Possible solution - provide form method and controller name:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadFile", "Controller", FormMethod.Get))
        { <input type="submit" value="Download" /> }
```

**or** try to use action link instead of form:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadFile", "Controller")
```

**or** try to provide direct url to the file:

```
<a href="~/App_Data/MyFile.pdf">Download</>
```

This isn't the best practice because of security reasons, but still you can try...
Also, You can wrap file location to some `@Html` helper method:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions {
    private const string FDir_AppData = "~/App_Data/";

    public static MvcHtmlString File(this HtmlHelper helper, string name){
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(Path.Combine(FDir_AppData, name));
    }
}
```

And in the view:

```
<a href="@Html.File("MyFile.pdf")">Download</>
```

Comment: My problem was that the APP_DATA folder was a reserved name. I could not take files from that folder. So I had to move my file to another folder.

Comment: I would definitely use the ActionLink method because this allows you to use an ActionFilter to authorize/authenticate whether or not the user is able to download the file. Typically, the link shouldn't even be shown if a user doesn't have rights to download it, but if the url was somehow obtained by a 3rd party, you're still in control of the security.

Answer (score 9):

Change the `DownloadFile` Action signature from:

```
 public ActionResult DownloadFile()
```

To:

```
 public FileResult DownloadFile()
```

In addition, I think that the `UrlEncode` of the file path is redundant, change it to:

```
return File(sDocument, "application/pdf", sDocument);
```

And make sure that this path does physically exist.

Comment: The file still are not downloaded.

Comment: I don't know. I expect the file under the download arrow (firefox). The site shows no errors. It looks like the system read something and than he finished.

Comment: This solution works for me (in MVC 4 and using Html.ActionLink in the razor view to build the download URL), so I much prefer it over the accepted answer: It not only looks like the simplest and cleanest solution, but also like what I imagine the MVC/Razor designers had in mind when they designed the API.