# How to remove initial blank lines from XmlWriter output?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4

Please, see the following image:
[image]

In English:

> XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity.
>   Location: https:// ****.com/sitemap Line Number 4, Column 1:

I can't properly create a sitemap, because I'm always stuck on that error. I don't know why but it seems like `XmlWriter` is adding exactly 3 blank lines before my `xml` tag. I've tried playing with XmlWriterSettings and lots of different things at no avail.

This is part of my code:

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
    context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/xml;";
    context.HttpContext.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    using (XmlWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(context.HttpContext.Response.Output))
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("urlset", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
...
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasWeller You're saying I should remove `charset=UTF-8` from the header?

Comment: Standard approach is to return [FileResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult(v=vs.118).aspx)/FileStreamResult instead of writing your own - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-mvc ... Not exactly what you asking, but likely what you actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks for the link, but this is way is how people make their sitemap.xml available using asp.net mvc. This is just one example: https://github.com/benfoster/Fabrik.Common/blob/master/src/Fabrik.Common.Web/ActionResults/SitemapResult.cs but you can find others. Anyway, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UTF-8 byte order mark (BOM) is counted as newlines. Remove the BOM to get rid of the 3 bytes `EF BB BF` by using `new UTF8Encoding(false)`:

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, 
new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false)}))
```

Alternatively, a `XmlTextWriter` works fine for me as well:

```
using (XmlWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
```

Comment: Thomas, thank you for the update, here's what I got so far, see if you can help me out. There are no constructors for TextWriter and UTF8Encoding class so I changed ContentEncoding from the TextWriter and now the xml header disappeared. Was that the expected behavior?

Comment: Sorry, i'm confused. TextWriter or XmlTextWriter? What is in your using-statement now? Also, let's clean up the comments a bit.

Comment: If my answer didn't solve the problem, you can also write your own answer and define what you have finally used.

Comment: Nah, you did help. I appreciate your time. I'm just fixing some nodes with invalid characters, hopefully that would do. I'm already seeing a page I wasn't that's why I accepted the answer and I'm assuming it'll work now as soon as fix those nodes :) Thanks again. PS: I updated my question with my current code.