# jsreports not adding .csv extension to file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, csv, jsreport

I'm using mysite.jsreportsonline.net to create a csv the end user downloads.  On the jsreports site under my login, it functions as it should be prompting me to download the file with the .csv extension.  For some reason in my MVC 4 application, it prompts for the download, but doesn't add the .csv extension.  in my controller I am pulling the report from mysite.jsreportonline.net with my login credentials.  Any clues as tyo why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was using `Response.AppendHeader` wrong.  Here's how it should have been coded:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=filename.csv");
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
```

Answer (score 0):

jsreport response headers include something like

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=report.csv
```

This instructs browser to open download dialog for report.csv.

If I understand it correctly you make a post request to jsreport from the controller and then return the stream you get back. You need to make sure you add such a header also to your response.

Comment: I'm using `ReportingService` which allows for the url string, username and password and `_reportingService.RenderAsync` which allows for shortid and input data. tried adding `Response.AddHeader` but that didn't work.  Also tried `FileExtension = "csv";` and that didn't work either.

Comment: You seems to have rather a common problem of returning files from mvc controllers. You should be able to return jsreport stream as any other. Did you try something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5830215/1660996

Comment: I'm adding `Response.AppendHeader("content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.csv", report.ToString());` and what that returns is "filename.csv- jsreport.Client.Report" as the filename to save as.

Comment: Still not working.  Using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application.Remove("- jsreport.Client.Report");`, `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();`, `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();`, `Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition: " + "attachment; filename=report.csv", report.ToString());`, `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";` with no luck.  Still wants to save it as "report.csv- jsreport.Client.Report"    Anyone out there got this to work in an MVC 4 application?