# ASP MVC Change Default Name of Displaing PDF. Working on Chrome but not on IE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

In my app i displaying PDF files. Everything work fine expect one. When i hit save button in Browser PDF Viewer the default name of file is take from name of the method :

My code :

```
    public ActionResult PdfViewer(Criteriacriteria)
    {
        var report= new Report().GetReport(criteria);

        if (report!= null)
        {
            string mimeType = "";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("inline; filename=Test_'{0}'",DateTime.Now));
            return File(report, "application/pdf", "Test");
        }
           return Content("No report found upon given parameters");

    }
```

The pdf displaing correct but when i saving it the default name is `PdfViewer`. As you can see in code i tried to change this name but whit no result. any idea ?

Thanks

Edit :

try to add code :

```
            var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
            {
                // for example foo.bak
                FileName = "test",

                // always prompt the user for downloading, set to true if you want 
                // the browser to try to show the file inline
                Inline = true,
            };
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", cd.ToString());
```

With no result

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: This don't help. File name is still 'PdfViewer'

Comment: Did you consider it might be your browser's PDF Viewer (which do you use?) that determines the filename? Adding a .pdf extension might help as well.

Comment: I try to add `.PDF` at end. And i try to open it on IE and FF. I will try on Chrome

Comment: It work on Chrome but i  need to do it on IE