# Downloading a file using mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am having problem while downloading a file using mvc application. I don't know what the problem is as my code is not throwing any error and i am new to mvc.

My code is as below:

```
    public FileResult DownloadDocument(JobModel data)
        {

            string filename = data.DocumentDetails[0].DocumentName;
            string filepath = data.DocumentDetails[0].Path;

            byte[] filedata = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(PathToSaveDocument + filepath));
            string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(Server.MapPath(PathToSaveDocument + filepath));

            var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
            {
                FileName = filename,
                Inline = true,
            };

            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

            return File(filedata, contentType);
}
```

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem ? Do you see any errors ? exception messages ? Did you try to put a break point in your code and inspected the variable values ?

Comment: try this you can change @Inline = false. help full link [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: @Shyju I don't get any errors but file is not downloaded using this code. I have inspected all the values using break points.

Comment: @VidhyadharGalande Still, i can't download the file to my local machine.

Comment: @JitenderSingh try to pass return File(filedata, contentType,filedata); work fine to my machine another link  [click here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rahul4_saxena/download-file-in-mvc-4/)

Comment: @VidhyadharGalande Sir it's still not working and neither it's giving any error.

Comment: @JitenderSingh can you share view code? (then edit your original code)