# File hyperlink points to localhost rather than Physical directory

Tags: asp.net, iis

Im having a asp.net application run on IIS 7.5
In one of the pages, there is a " view file" link. This points to( in code) a physical directory eg: D:\Campoff\policy.

Whenever the user clicks on the link, a file under that physical directory get downloaded.
However, when i run the application on IIS, when i point to that " View file" link, it points to http://localhost/Campoff/policy.
this gives the 404 error( FIle not found).

The location of the physical directory is in Web.config file in a key value pair.And that is being addressed in the code.

Here's what I'm calling

```
protected string getLinkText(string policyNo) 
{ 
    string str = ""; 
    if (File.Exists(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Insurance‌​PolicyFileDir") + 
        policyNo + ".pdf")) 
        str = policyNo; 
        return str; 
}
```

`str` ends up being localhost/insurancepolicydir instead of d:\insurancepolicydir

Please help me understand, what is happening  or what is wrong with my setting?

Comment: You CANNOT download a file using a file URI through a browser.  You must serve the file through the website.  There's tons of info out there about how to serve static or dynamic files via asp.net.  Search for "asp.net how to download a file" and get results like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: You can describe your code for a year, or you could simply [edit] and show us your actual code.

Comment: This is the code that gets called , when the text link is clicked.            protected string getLinkText(string policyNo)
  {
    string str = "";
    if (File.Exists(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("InsurancePolicyFileDir")  + policyNo + ".pdf"))
      str = policyNo;
    return str;
  }                                                                                                                             The str is showing http://localhost/insurancepolicydir instead of d:\insurancepolicydir

Comment: Please don't throw your code in a comment.  You can [edit] (<= LOOK! It's a link! Click on it!) your question at any time to improve it.  It looks like you haven't debugged your code.  Simply walking through it while executing would tell you that `str = policyNo;` is absolutely positively wrong. There's more going on here, so I still can't answer.  But you need to stop guessing and debug.  Stop whatever you are doing and read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx