# .Net MVC returning a File

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm working a Controller that will generate/retrieve files. These will optionally set headers.

```
   public IActionResult SampleFileReport()
    {
```

I see the return type is IActionResult (a data contract). I see inside the function I can still set 
   response.ContentType

Is there a preferred pattern for how to set ContentType in a controller?

I'm thinking it should be part of the DataContract and setting response.contentype is an anti-pattern, however I see examples such as this that utilize it. [Returning a file to View/Download in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is return `File`:

```
public IActionResult SampleFileReport()
{
    // do stuff

    return File(bytes, mimetype, filename);
}
```

`File` also has overloads that accept `Stream` and `string` (path and filename to a file on the filesystem) in addition to `byte[]`. The `mimetype` is your content type, e.g. `application/pdf`, `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` (Excel), etc. The final `filename` param is optional. If it's provided, a `Content-Disposition: attachment` header is sent with the response, which prompts the browser to pop a download dialog. Otherwise, the default `Content-Disposition: inline` is used, and the browser will try to load the returned file directly the browser tab/window, assuming the mime-type is supported for native rendering the browser. If not, then you'll get a download dialog, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about MVC (not .NET Core) then you can change `IActionResult` to `FileContentResult`

```
public FileContentResult SampleFileReport() 
{

    byte[] fileBytes = GetFileBytes();
    return File(fileBytes, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "fileName");
}
```

Just checked this class still exists. [FileContentResult .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filecontentresult.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_FileContentResult__ctor_System_Byte___Microsoft_Net_Http_Headers_MediaTypeHeaderValue_)

Comment: thank you, I had tagged as .net core (but also mvc not sure if they're mutually exclusive) I am using .net core. Why did Microsoft take it out then?

Comment: They didn't. `IActionResult` is an abstraction. There's no need to ever specify a specific action return type, even in ASP.NET MVC, but definitely not in ASP.NET Core.