# File result from asp.net MVC controller returns the view html string instead of the file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3

I have a very weird behaviour in a legacy repository that I cloned and try to work on.

There is an action for downloading files (files are hosted on AWS):
(redundant code omitted for clarity).

```
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Entity(EntityModel entity)
        {
               using (Stream stream = downloadFileObject(model.Updates[GetUpdateNumberFromQueryString()].UpdateLink))
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await stream.CopyToAsync(ms).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/octet-stream", "The file.exe");
                }
        }
```

The `DownloadFileObject` method connects to AWS, creates a request and returns the response stream:

```
public Stream GetS3FileObject(string objectKey, string fileName)
    {
        GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = objectKey,
        };
        GetObjectResponse response = s3Client.GetObject(request);
        return response.ResponseStream;
    }
```

This returns a proper stream with no errors, I can see that the lenght indicates something around 35 mb, which is the proper size of the file I am getting.

Now, I tried several approaches for returning this stream as downloadable file, and they all result in something very weird.

**Instead of getting the file, the browser retrieves a 110kb text file which pretty much looks like my current view html...**

The returned HTML contains the following error message (apart from the regular site content)

> Error executing child request for handler
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.
>   OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used.

I tried several approaches, where the first and most obvious was just:

```
var stream = DownloadFileObject(model.Updates[GetUpdateNumberFromQueryString()].UpdateLink);
return File(stream, "application/octet-stream", "The file.exe");
```

Then I tried to copy that stream to a byte array and return that - however, in all cases the result is the same.
Up to the last moment, the debugger shows that my stream/byte array is 35mb large.

Here are the headers:

[image]

[image]

Also, the rendered Download button html is as below:

`<a href="/support/product-support/software/TheProductName" class="btn btn-default">Download update</a>`

And the button is being created in the view without any HTML helpers (Action.Link() etc)

`<a href="@updateVersions.Link" class="btn btn-default">@Model.SiteLabelDownloadUpdate</a>`

Any ideas what can be going on?

Comment: Please show the request and response headers for that http request, from Chrome Developer Tools (Network tab).

Comment: @mjwills - added

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5830215/6803592

Comment: @Devilscomrade - nope, that's not it, thanks. (I implemented the content disposition setting and the behaviour is the same.)