# How create file way in c# download?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, download

I am trying to download a folder that is on my drive C:/. My program doesn't show any error, it just doesn't work. I don't know what am I doing wrong, I think this folder name could be wrong? Or code?
This is my code :

```
        [HttpPost]

    public HttpResponseMessage DownloadFile(DownloadInput input)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input.DosyaAdi))
        {
            string filePath = "C:/Uploads";
            string fullPath = filePath + "/" + input.FileID + "/" + input.FileNm;
            return CreateResponseFileContent(fullPath);
            //string fullPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + filePath + "/" + input.SorunID + "/" + input.DosyaAdi;
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage CreateResponseFileContent(string fullPath)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        try
        {
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var fileStream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open);
            result.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fullPath;
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Gone);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning a file to View/Download in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Also if you want to only get something from the server (or your drive C in this case), use HttpGet, if you want to send something to the server, use HttpPost. Explained better [here](https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/)

Comment: I think  this solution  fine , ı try now  thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use File action result?

```
public FileResult DownloadFile()
{
    ...
    return File(file, document.ContentType);
}
```

Comment: I am trying download in my folder  not database, is this code for my problem??

Comment: @YilmazFurkan I didn't use any database related concept, It is a normal variable with name "file" which contains your file path.

Comment: Okey I understand