# How to download pptx file from one folder to client system - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, download

I have .pptx files in one location which I need to need to download in client system where ever user want to save or default browser download location.

Controller Code

```
var fileName = "textFile20210323.pptx";
var filePath = @"\\Depts\IT\TestFolder\";
var fileNamewithPath = $"{filePath}{fileName}";

Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/x-mspowerpoint";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileNamewithPath);
Response.WriteFile(fileNamewithPath);
Response.Flush();

return Json(new { success = "success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Script

```
    function DownloadFile(args) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Home/DownloadFile",
        data: { "json": JSON.stringify(args) },
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        success: function (data) {

            alert("Success");
        }
    });
}
```

Any other approach is acceptable.

Comment: Why not simply return `File()` rather than going down the ajax route? Also check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-asp-net-mvc) question which should provide some more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller.cs

```
    public FileResult DownloadFile(string FilePath, string FileName)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePath) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileName))
        {
            return File(FilePath, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint", FileName);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

View.cshtml

```
 <a onClick="DownloadFile(this)">Download</a>
```

Script.js

```
    function DownloadFile(args) {
        window.location.href = "../Home/DownloadFile?FilePath=" + args.FilePath + "&FileName=" + args.Name;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the simple approach is to not use Ajax at all for this.  The following gives the user a link to download the file to their local computer.

View:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("GetFile", new { controller = "Home", path = @"\\Depts\IT\TestFolder\textFile20210323.pptx" })">Download File</a>
```

Controller:

```
using System.IO;

public FilePathResult GetFile(string path)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
    return File(path, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
}
```