# My MVC View displays file content into the view instead of downloading as a file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I found this link. [ASP.NET MVC download image rather than display in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007652/asp-net-mvc-download-image-rather-than-display-in-browser?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I tried everything and my action method dumps the file into the view instead of downloading. I would like to be able to download the file separately. Thanks

```
        if (extension.ToLower() == ".docx")
        { // Handle *.jpg and   
            contentType = "application/docx";
        }
        else if (extension.ToLower() == ".jpg")
        {// Handle *.gif   
            contentType = "image/jpeg jpeg jpg jpe";
        }
        else if (extension.ToLower() == ".pdf")
        {// Handle *.pdf   
            contentType = "application/pdf";
        }
        Response.ContentType = contentType; // "application/force-download";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
        Response.WriteFile(FilePath );
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();[![View after clicking download button][1]][1]
```

Comment: Try using `application/octet-stream` mime type and see if the browser gives you the options to save rather than displaying it

Comment: I did. it is still acting the same.

Comment: What does the response header look like?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably similar with these:

[How can I present a file for download from an MVC controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730699/how-can-i-present-a-file-for-download-from-an-mvc-controller)

[Returning a file to View/Download in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-asp-net-mvc?rq=1)

Instead of using `Response.WriteFile`, you can return `FileResult` or `FileStreamResult` from action method by using this code:

```
    if (extension.ToLower() == ".docx")
    { // Handle *.jpg and   
        contentType = "application/docx";
    }
    else if (extension.ToLower() == ".jpg")
    {// Handle *.gif   
        contentType = "image/jpeg jpeg jpg jpe";
    }
    else if (extension.ToLower() == ".pdf")
    {// Handle *.pdf   
        contentType = "application/pdf";
    }
    Response.ContentType = contentType; // "application/force-download";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);

    // returning the file for download as FileResult
    // third input parameter is optional
    return File(FileName, contentType, Server.UrlEncode(Filename));
```

NB: As Leo said in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36776089/6378815, `Response.AppendHeader` method may cause browser to fail rendering the file content if the response header already contains `Content-Disposition` section. You may want try this way:

```
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
```

Additional reference:

[Response.WriteFile() -- not working asp net mvc 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458477/response-writefile-not-working-asp-net-mvc-4-5/15577763)