# Forcing image to download

Tags: c#, silverlight, download, httpwebrequest, browser

I'm using a WebBrowser control in Silverlight and I'm setting it to a local HTML page. The HTML page has various links and they all work fine. Can I make it so that if the user clicks on an image file, it downloads to their system (or does the default behavior of the broweser) instead of displaying on the webpage? The main question is, is it possible to do this if I don't have access to the server itself? Thanks
**edit** - Is it possible to send an HTTPWebRequest to get the image and then edit the response headers, all from the client? This may be an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way of doing this is to send the **Content-Disposition** HTTP header with **attachment** as the value. See here for more on this: [Uses of content-disposition in an HTTP response header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012437/uses-of-content-disposition-in-an-http-response-header)

But if you don't have access to the server, I don't think you can achieve this.