# I want HTML link to .ics file to open in calendar app when clicked, currently opens file as plain text. Suggestions?

Tags: html, hyperlink, calendar, icalendar

I am linking to an `.ics` file exported from Apple iCal in an HTML web page.

```
<a href="calendar.ics">
```

This link will open the `calendar.ics` file as plain text in my browser (Chrome). I want automatic opening in Outlook or iCal or other calendar apps. What can I add to the link tag in order to produce the desired behavior? What about modifying the HTTP headers on `.ics` files?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: What is the HTTP Content-Type header on your response right now?  It should be `text/calendar`.

Comment: The header in the response is 'text/plain' when simply linking to the .ics file.

Comment: can you get your server to serve it up as `text/calendar` and see if that gets your client browser to treat it properly?

Comment: The files are being served from a typical shared host PHP LAMP type environment. How would I modify the headers on something like that? I'm not sure I can even use mod-rewrite or give Apache any config options.

Comment: to have browsers treat a link as a download, you should add the `Content-Disposition:attachment` header, optionally with a `filename` argument. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012437/uses-of-content-disposition-in-an-http-response-header

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your site is built on Linux like mine you can simply add a line to your htaccess file to make it open as a download instead of a text page.

add this to your htaccess file:

```
AddType text/calendar .ics
```

Answer (score 35):

If your calendar file is not static, you should consider the `webcal` scheme in addition to [setting the MIME type to `text/calendar` in Ryan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19367636/241211).

```html
<a href="webcal://example.com/path/calendar.ics">
```

Rather than downloading a one-time file, the attendees' calendar programs will periodically poll for updates to your calendar. This will let their calendars add new events and update changed events to match your published list.

### Platform and application support

#### Desktop

- Calendar applications like Outlook and iCal can register with the OS to handle links with that scheme.
- In [many browsers](https://caniuse.com/registerprotocolhandler), a specific website like Google Calendar or Outlook.com can ask to handle `webcal` links.

#### Mobile

- iOS can import calendar events with `webcal` and a `text/calendar` type.
- Android is an odd case:

  - Despite [a merge request](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/+/88711/3/AndroidManifest.xml) to add file support to AOSP, it was never put in.
  - Third party packages like [ICSx<sup>5</sup>](https://icsx5.bitfire.at/) can sign up to subscribe to a `webcal` and provide the events to the user's primary calendar application.

Comment: [Looks like](http://www.stefanhayden.com/blog/2005/08/08/my-adventures-with-hcal-ical-webcal-and-their-lack-of-support/) IE does not support this in 2005. How is the support now?

Comment: @PiTheNumber With no additional verification, it [sounds like](http://news.mullerdigital.com/2010/03/08/webcal-link-in-ie/) you need Outlook 2007+ or some other program that signs up to handle the `webcal` protocol on your computer. It's not IE, it's "Do you have something to handle `.ics` files?" In the absence of such a program, an [RFC 5545](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545) file is not going to help you much.

Comment: This doesn't work with current Android devices either.

Comment: When I put this in IE I get a Chrome popup and when I let it open the ics file it just opens a blank tab.

Comment: Ok here's the thing: Chrome recognizes it as well if you put it into a link (as opposed to putting it directly into address bar and hitting enter): `<a href="webcal://path/to/.ics">sub link</a>`

Comment: You can refer to the CanIUse for browser support, @see https://caniuse.com/?search=registerProtocolHandler