# open .ics file with outlook from browser

Tags: java, jsp, outlook, icalendar, ical4j

I'm developing an application to export calendars. The problem that I have is that the calendar is downloaded instead of opened with Outlook. Here is my code:

1) There is an image link in the main page to export the calendar:

```
<img src="/calendar.png" width="32" Style="width: 32px; height:32px;" title="Calendar" onClick="javascript:document.getElementById('exportCal').submit();">

<form id="exportCal" action="Calendar.jsp" target="_blank" method="post">
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" ID="calendarData" NAME="calendarData" VALUE=""/>
</form>
```

2) In the jsp that the link redirects to, I generate the .ics (using the iCal4j library) file and attach it to the response:

```
response.setHeader ("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"mycalendar.ics\"");
response.setContentType("text/calendar");

Calendar calendar = new Calendar();
calendar.getProperties().add(new ProdId("-//Ben Fortuna//iCal4j 1.0//EN"));
calendar.getProperties().add(Version.VERSION_2_0);
calendar.getProperties().add(CalScale.GREGORIAN);

java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, java.util.Calendar.DECEMBER);
cal.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 25);

// initialise as an all-day event..
VEvent christmas = new VEvent(new Date(cal.getTime()), "Christmas Day");

// Generate a UID for the event..
UidGenerator ug = new UidGenerator("1");
christmas.getProperties().add(ug.generateUid());

calendar.getComponents().add(christmas);
System.out.println(calendar);

ServletOutputStream fout = response.getOutputStream();

CalendarOutputter outputter = new CalendarOutputter();
outputter.output(calendar, fout);

fout.flush();
```

And then, the .ics is downloaded. But what I really want to do is open it with Outlook. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a browser-specific behavior. The only way to avoid the automatic downloading (*in chrome*) is by utilizing the **webcal** protocol [as suggested in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7532838/175679). Webcal is typically only used for dynamic calendar subscriptions - not static calendar items. If you open the ICS after download - it should open in Outlook.

```xml
<p>A <a href="webcal://mycalendar.ics">webcal ics link</a></p>
```

Comment: I knew about the webcal protocol but i thought that it was only for static files. Because in order to put a link like that you should have created (and stored) the file previously and then link to it. So every time the page with the link is opened a new calendar file (different for each user) will be generated that may or may not be downloaded. Also, I've tried that solution and I don't know how to save the file in the server so it can be downloaded later. Please correct me if i am wrong and point me to the right direction as I am a newbie with jsp. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: In current Firefox i get: Prevented navigation to “webcal://www.mydomain/myscript” due to an unknown protocol. The policy about this has appearently changed: https://www.fxsitecompat.dev/en-CA/docs/2020/navigation-to-unknown-protocol-will-be-blocked/