# I want to create a link to .ics file, but it doesn't work in Firefox and chrome

Tags: hyperlink, outlook, icalendar

I am linking to an .ics file exported from Outlook in an HTML web page.

```
 <a href="calendar.ics" >Save the Date</a>
```

This link will open 'calendar.ics' file as plain text in browser (Chrome and Firefox). I want automatic download the .ics file. What can I add to the link tag in order to produce the desired behavior?

I tried `webcal://`, but it will add a calendar tag in Outlook 2010. It's too much for me.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: have you looked at:

 - http://stackoverflow.com/q/5329529/1167333
 - http://stackoverflow.com/q/1012437/1167333

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but i think this should work.

In your .htaccess file:

```
<filesMatch "\.ics$">
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Content-type "text/calendar"
</ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

or

```
<filesMatch "\.ics$">
ForceType 'text/calendar'
</filesMatch>
```

or

```
AddType text/calendar .ics
```

Comment: What is your question? Also, try testing first before posting. -Sorry, I was using the edit feature of SO, and thought this was a question.  Sorry for the confusion!