# URL for opening a link in a calendar application

Tags: html, url, calendar

This is a html link/href/url when you want to open a link with an email client (like outlook)

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again">Send Mail</a>
```

What should be an html link when you want to open the link with a calendar client (like calendar from microsoft outlook or similar calendar application) in order for them to also save some information regarding appointments/events?

Is there a general approach to these urls to be able to open with them different applications?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329529/i-want-html-link-to-ics-file-to-open-in-calendar-app-when-clicked-currently-op

Answer (score 1):

There's no common link to be used across different calendars (Google, Outlook, etc...) you can work with some of those, but my suggestion is to use free "link builders" like http://addtocalendar.com or https://www.addevent.com for example.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by creating below registry entry

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\outlookwebcal]
@="URL:Outlook Add Internet Calendar"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\outlookwebcal\shell]
@="open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\outlookwebcal\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\outlookwebcal\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\office16\\Outlook.exe\" /select outlook:calendar"
```

then markup should be like

```
<button id="outlookCalendarBtn" onclick="window.open('outlookwebcal:')">
   Open Outlook Calendar
</button>
```