# How to allow website visitors to directly subscribe to ics calendar file?

Tags: hyperlink, calendar, icalendar, agenda

For my first website project I am making a .ics file filter. I've managed to filter the .ics files according to the user's input and was able to host the .ics files on my website. The .ics files are accessible through a link, e.g. sitename.com/file_1.ics.

Now I would like to give users a simple button to add the .ics file to their calendar app of choice (Google, Apple, Outlook...). The reason why I want this, is because adding the .ics file manually can be cumbersome for some users.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you just add a Download Button? https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_a_download.asp ?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329529/i-want-html-link-to-ics-file-to-open-in-calendar-app-when-clicked-currently-op