# Is there a way to set a file extension when pushing a dynamically created file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a project where a page dynamically creates a .pdf file.  I would like users to have the option to right-click the link, and "Save As."  While the saving works as expected, the default text in the save dialog is "pdfMaker.aspx.cs" and must be changed to "xxxx.pdf" by the user.

Is there a way to push a default file name and extension to the user along with the file?  I'd like the text in the save dialog to read something like "somePdfName.pdf" by default.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012437/uses-of-content-disposition-in-an-http-response-header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [content-disposition](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519) header. This should be added to the current HttpContext response.

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=SomeName.pdf");
```