# Save output of CGI script under different filename than the script name

Tags: http, cgi, filenames

I have a Python CGI script `script.py` running on a server. It produces a CSV file as output.
I want computer-inexperienced people that don't know about file extensions to be able to just save the file to their hard drive and use it by double-clicking.

The problem: If they now click "OK" in the save dialog of the browser, the saved file's name is `script.py`, instead of `script.csv`.

How can I set some sort of "default filename" from within the CGI? Maybe some HTTP header trickery?
I don't have access to the server configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set a [`Content-Disposition` header](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt), with a `filename` attribute. See [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012437/uses-of-content-disposition-in-an-http-response-header) for some discussion.

Yours would look like:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=script.csv
```

As well as setting the filename, this will tell the browser to save the file, rather than to open it inline.

Comment: Worked instantly, thank you very much.

I think that it's still helpful to have my question around here because it might be easier to be searched for than the question mentioned by you.

Comment: Evidently - if the other question had been easy to find, you would have found it!

Comment: A short note to anyone who later reads this and wants what I want: for the file to display but when the user tries to save it, it uses the substitute filename.  To do that, use the above but use `inline` instead of `attachment`.