# How can I force download with html and/or javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a this code:

```
    <a href="http://mysite.com/song.mp3">My Song</a>
```

How can I make it so that instead of the user having to right click, save as, they just click the link and **BAM** it downloads?

Comment: Not possible without a server-side language like PHP or manipulating the server-side configuration (like the .htaccess file in Apache)

Comment: im pretty sure theres a way my friend.

Comment: @beardtwizzle This one has sound effects **BAM**!

Answer (score 4):

On the server side, you can send back a `Content-Disposition` header, which should work (although its off-spec). See example here:

[Uses of content-disposition in an HTTP response header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012437/uses-of-content-disposition-in-an-http-response-header)

In future you'll be able to benefit from the [new `download` attribute](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download), part of HTML5.

Comment: it seems that `download` attrbute not works now

Answer (score 1):

The reason this can't be done without a server-side language is the potential security threats that it poses for users.

You wouldn't like "accidentally" downloading a virus from a site, now would you?

However, as long as the user's browser doesn't support displaying (or playing, in your case) any filetype, it will automatically prompt the user if they want to download the file. So if a browser doesn't offer support for playing mp3 files (I know Chrome does, maybe Firefox), then it should be "automatically downloaded" when clicked.

If you really need another way, though, it can be done with ASP. [Here](http://www.psacake.com/web/if.asp) is a tutorial.

Comment: so is there a way to do it without php headers?

Comment: It [can be done with ASP](http://www.psacake.com/web/if.asp), if you're open to it.

Comment: @user1109075: you need to send headers, like it or not.

Comment: Why "asking the user if he/she want to save a file" would impose more potential security threats than "automatically downloading and opening the file without asking anything"?

Answer (score -3):

Audio files by default gets played by audio player/plug-in. 
You should put the files in a ".zip", and write the code to download it:

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/song.zip">My Song</a>
```

That instantly sets the default action to force download.

Comment: This is not completely correct, in some actual browsers the mp3 is played inside the browser, there's not nedded any audio player nor plugin. And soaud tries to make a downloadable link for his songs, creating a zip file is a horrible way to do this.

Answer (score -3):

```
<a type="application/mpeg" href="song.mp3">song link</a>
```

This will work on every Browser today, except on mobile dispositives.
I would like a method with Javascript or simple html to perform this although.
I've tried the meta content-disposition and still don't work.