# How to force a Download File prompt instead of displaying it in-browser with HTML?

Tags: html

```
 <a href="sample.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

If I click Download button, this target blank is opening a new window.

But I need it to prompt a dialog for saving this file. How can I achieve this?
[image]

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364946/how-to-make-pdf-file-downloadable-in-html-link

Comment: another duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/10974734/383793

Comment: Even though those are Java, not EcmaScript, the point is in the Content-Disposition response header.

Comment: Yes but the OP asked how to do that with HTML (at least that's what I perceived)

Comment: @rkon, this last duplicate is an exact duplicate of the question.. You should flag this question as a duplicate and answer the other one, if you feel your answer adds anything the the existing corpus.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the questions referenced in the closure. This one is asking for an HTML solution (which Kostas provided) and the referenced questions are server side solutions.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is something that you cannot absolutely control with HTML itself.

If the user is having a browser with PDF reading capabilities (or a plugin) and the corresponding settings to open PDF files in-browser, the PDF will open like that.

The PDF opens in a new tab simple because of your `target="_blank"`, which has nothing to do with a download prompt.

If you are using HTML5 you can use the [download attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute):

```
<a href="sample.pdf" download="sample.pdf">Download</a>
```

If you have a back-end service which you can control or you feel like fiddling with your Web Server, you can always look for setting the right `Content-Disposition`. See this SO question for [some nice discussion on Content-Disposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395151/content-dispositionwhat-are-the-differences-between-inline-and-attachment).

Comment: If only HTML5 is used I agree with this answer, +1. Though, Here's the [**compatibility table**](http://caniuse.com/#search=download%20attribute) of download attribute. This must be known.

Comment: Absolutely, that's why I started with the long answer and only at the end mentioned the HTML5 feature :) Thanks for the compatibility link

Comment: Yep, and you did well. It'll be better to use a server-side language that forces download. But this is up to the OP

Comment: HTML 5 download attribute did this ..thank you

Comment: -1, this answer is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/8613899/383793

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the correctness of the answer. It is just not useful. Flagging it a duplicate will a) provide OP with the answer he/she needs and b) educate him/her to search SO before posting to SO. The fact that you find it cumbersome to wade through all possible duplicates only illustrates my point, there is no need for yet another duplicate that *adds* to the pile of possible duplicates.

Comment: [We're not alone](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/383793) in our different points of view. ;-)

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Safari 8.0 on OS X 10.10.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling down voting the answer because the question is a dupe sounds ridiculous, why does that have anything to do with the answerer? It'd be one thing if he copied an answer *on the same question*, but this is not that case. Actually this post comes up first on Google AND has more up votes (by an order of magnitude) than the one you linked to. Down voting is not a mechanism for "flagging as a duplicate", it's a mechanism for down voting.

Comment: What about .svg file? download attribute downloads .svg image and also displays in browser window.

Comment: @mabesadze, if you still haven't had your answer: yes, you can do it with absolutely anything, including SVG and even HTML pages.

Answer (score 2):

Modern browsers open known types such as jpg, pdf, etc. instead of downloading. Here is the way how I overcome this issue. Firstly fetched the entire blob with javascript and served it as a blob to user.

```js
async function download(dataurl, fileName) {
    const response = await fetch(dataurl);
    const blob = await response.blob();

    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = fileName;
    link.click();
}
```