# IOS save PDF after accessing from WebView, Cordova

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, pdf

I have an app that displays me a website (uiwebview). In that website i have some LINKS that open me pdf s in webview. What do i want is... can i make, if i'm pressing on a link, pdf to download it instead of open it? Thank you.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825871/how-to-force-a-download-file-prompt-instead-of-displaying-it-in-browser-with-htm

Comment: I don't think u understood my question.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps put some code up? It might to understand your requirement a bit better

Comment: So.. If I'm trying to open a .pdf file from my ios app, it will open a pdf, without a navigation control (no close/back button to my app - like in attached photo)
https://postimg.org/image/8rtst9fv5/

Answer (score 0):

[Cordova-PDFReader-IOS](https://github.com/etabard/Cordova-PDFReader-IOS)
**To install from command line:**

```
cordova plugin add com.lesfrancschatons.cordova.plugins.pdfreader
```

Supported URI scheme: file For other schemes, please download it first with cordova plugin fileTransfer.

```
//Open a pdf
PDFReader.open('absolutepath.pdf', options, success, error);

//Available options
{
    password: null,
    flatUI: true,
    showShadows: true,
    enableThumbs: true,
    disableRetina: false,
    enablePreview: true,
    bookmarks: true,
    landscapeDoublePage: true,
    landscapeSingleFirstPage: true,
    toolbarBackgroundColor: null,
    textColor: null,
    enableShare: false,
    page: 2
}

//Event when PDF Reader is closed
document.addEventListener('PDFReaderClosed', function() {console.log('closed');})

//Clear PDF Reader cache
PDFReader.clearCache(filePath, finishedCallback);
```