# Downloading image using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following code is working fine here in sandbox and I am able to down  it but in my machine and browser, using Chrome it is opening the images in next tab instead of downloading them as it is supposed to be by clicking on `.imgs`

Why might this happen and how can I prevent it to open in new page and just be download?

```js
 $('section img').each(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('#imageBox').append('<a class="imgs" href="' + $this.attr('src') + '"  download>Download</a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imageBox"></div>
<section>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Perspolis_FC.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
<img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/manchester_united/manchester_united_PNG15.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
</section>
```

Comment: Have you tried the suggested solution here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825871/how-to-force-a-download-file-prompt-instead-of-displaying-it-in-browser-with-htm

Comment: For me your snippet is work as expected, it is download me the image on Chrome `Version 63.0.3239.132`

Comment: Are you trying to do it from inside an iframe?

Comment: Hi Munim , yes I think the images are inside an iframe