# How to download a RAR File?

Tags: html, download, rar

I've made a website but the problem is when people is trying to download the file instead it opens the file not save as or download the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I force download with html and/or javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613725/how-can-i-force-download-with-html-and-or-javascript)

Comment: Doesn't a simple search on google offer you information about that? You need to send out a http header. You want to add information on _how_ to handle some object you send. So the information cannot be _part of_ that object. You need to add it to the protocol layer, so a header entry.

Answer (score 0):

use `<a href="./assets/file.rar" download>Download file</a>`

Comment: I've use this <a href="paints/ma.rar" download>Download</a>

Comment: But it open's the file instead of downloading it, if you wanna try Click This ravens-hangar.tk/repaints.html and try to download a file? Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adderrrr/d59x3Lgx/ I do not know, but it should work.

Comment: I think the problem is the file type I'll be trying to change it from .rar to .zip