# How do I make a button link that will download a file to the users computer once clicked?

Tags: html, dreamweaver, flash-cs5

I have several buttons on a Download page that I want to link to different movies stored on the server so that once the user clicks the download button the movie will download to their computer. How do I do this? I thought it was simply a case of putting the directory path to the relevant file into the link for the button?

Here's the page: http://www.infomaticfilms.com/jack/infomatics/download.htm

Any help would be appreciated.

Jack

Comment: You are linking movies correctly... _IF_ the movie actually is on your server _and_ on that path...

Comment: It is working just fine here, love the page design btw, looks really cool

Comment: How do you link to the movie?

Comment: The link for "Strawman" works for me; the other two links are (I assume) intentionally incomplete. (Actually the second link is missing "videos" in the URL.) And the page does indeed look quite cool.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want the user to be presented with a Save As dialog instead of just opening the file in the browser?

There are really two components that make this happen:

1. The user's browser is configured to download that type instead of open it directly.  You have no control over this, it's up to the user's own configuration.
2. Your server *suggests* to the browser that it should download that type instead of open it directly.  This is done via a header value in your server's response.

The [header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) you're looking for is called [Content Disposition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html).  [How you use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012437/uses-of-content-disposition-in-an-http-response-header) is up to your server-side capabilities.  But basically you want to set it to something like:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.mpg"
```

This response header tells the browser that what you're sending it is a file and should be locally saved as one.  (Remember that HTTP by itself has no notion of "files", only requests and responses with headers and data.)