# Download files with non-ASCII characters in the name

Tags: php, html, apache, filenames

My website allows users to upload files with any name. Some names, of course, will have non-ASCII characters. When a user uploads a file, I save it in a folder with its original name. However, when I try to download it, by accessing its location (for example, `files/Tolstoy - How much land does a man need?.pdf`), I get a 404. Is there some way to solve this, so that the files remain with their original name? Via Apache, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, just use url encoding, known also as [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)? that's meant to handle the urls in web. All urls printed to HTML should be url encoded.

For PHP, [rawurlencode](http://php.net/rawurlencode) should be used, as it should be standards-compliant, which [urlencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) isn't.

Edit: for this issue

> PHP encodes "é" as "e%26%23769%3B", instead of "e%CC%81"

`e%CC%81` would be UTF-8 for `é`. `e%26%23769%3B` would be for `e&#769;`, which is an HTML entity for the same. This means that you're doing either explicit htmlentities() call there before urlencoding, or your server setup does that automatically. It's not strictly needed if proper character sets are in place (only htmlspecialchars call is actually needed), but it shouldn't break anything either.

Some online tools if you want to test these out:

- http://htmlentities.net/ to test converting html entities back and forth
- http://www.hypergurl.com/urlencode.html to test url encoding back and forth, with both UTF-8 and ASCII

Comment: Sorry the delay, I had to leave the computer. Using `urlencode` was also my first idea, but I can't get it to work. Here is a link to what I'm doing, might help: http://filechan.net/

Comment: For some reason, PHP encodes "é" as "e%26%23769%3B", instead of "e%CC%81". This may point to where the problem is.

Comment: urlencode() is something proprietary to php, rawurlencode is what you should use, since that one at least tries to be standard-compliant.

Comment: @FelipeSchenone added an explanation for that

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: convert filenames to ASCII at upload. You will be happy with it.

Comment: That should work, but I'd prefer to keep the names untouched. Is that possible?

Comment: You may trick with *content-disposition* header. You can tell any file name you like with it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012437/uses-of-content-disposition-in-an-http-response-header

Answer (score 0):

Well, for some reason that I still don't understand, using `rawurlencode()` instead of `urlencode()` made it work.

However, the character `é` (among others, I'm sure) is still being encoded strangely (`e%26%23769%3B` instead of simply `%C3%A9`). Even stranger is that the links containing it work.

Comment: Using `rawurlencode` solved my problem, so this is the answer that actually helped me out. However, after some edits, eis's answer is now more accurate and complete, so I chose it as the correct one.