# JavaScript: save base64 string as file

Tags: javascript, file, base64

I have a base64 string, file type. File type can be image, text or even pdf. I need to show `download` link and when user clicks it should start downloading as expected file. 
Concisely, server sends me file as base64 string, and I need to save it as file on browser. How can I save base64 string as file on browser? It would be best if solution works on IE9 also.

Answer (score 18):

Adapted from https://gist.github.com/RichardBray/23decdec877c0e54e6ac2bfa4b0c512f to work on Firefox.

```js
function downloadBase64File(contentBase64, fileName) {
    const linkSource = `data:application/pdf;base64,${contentBase64}`;
    const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    downloadLink.href = linkSource;
    downloadLink.target = '_self';
    downloadLink.download = fileName;
    downloadLink.click(); 
}
```

Comment: There's a syntax error here: a "function" keyword is missing.

Comment: The file starts to download then I get a "Failed - Network error"

Comment: @MadMac I had the same error. I had entered the wrong url. The correct format is "data:[fileMimeType];base64,[base64Content]"

Answer (score 16):

You can use [download.js](http://danml.com/download.html).

```
download(base64String, filename, mimeType)
```

Comment: That being said, this helped me the most of any answers. +1

Comment: This opens a 'save file as' dialog for me. Can't it automatically save the image?

Comment: @nclsvh, this part is up to your browser. It may be configured to ask you any time or not.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this from js to download pdf.

Use:

`document.location = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + base64String`

Comment: I think, in a SPA or a full ajax scenario, not opening another tab or not leaving current behavior is more suitable.

Comment: This resulted in `Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL: data:image/jpeg;base64, ...`. Unlike the OP, I tried to convert `base64String` into a jpeg file instead of PDF, which might cause this issue

Answer (score 1):

You get the effect you desire (web page showing a link, and when user clicks, the save as dialog pops up) when the appropriate response headers are present when the browser requests the resource:

Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="yourfilename.extension"

If you're getting the file from the server as a base64 string embedded in your html, perhaps you can skip the embedding and simply embed a direct link to the file on your server, having the server serve it up to the user.

[Related SO on Content-Disposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012437/uses-of-content-disposition-in-an-http-response-header)