# PDF force download as opposed to open in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razorpdf

I am using RazorPDF and I would like to force download the PDF as opposed to open in browser tab. How do I do this? Thanks

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string Id)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Pdf");
}

public PdfResult Pdf()
{
    // With no Model and default view name.  Pdf is always the default view name
    return new PdfResult();
}
```

Comment: You need to set `content-disposition` in the response header -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012437/uses-of-content-disposition-in-an-http-response-header.

Comment: How do I do that in the above code?

Comment: I haven't used RazorPDF, but you could probably do it be adding the code from the linked answer in your action before you return the PDF file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding the `content-disposition` header before returning the `PDFResult` object.

```
public PdfResult Pdf()
{
  Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=YourSanitazedFileName.pdf");

  // With no Model and default view name.  Pdf is always the default view name
  return new PdfResult();
}
```

Comment: IronGeek, I don't have any .pdf file to return. So I am not sure if your code will work in my case. Thanks

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner You don't have to, it could be any name. You could even use random name for it. The browser will use that name as the filename to download in the Download File Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the "Content-Disposition" header; for example setting "Content-Disposition" to "attachment; filename=FileName.pdf" will prompt the user (typically) with a "Save as: FileName.pdf" dialog, rather than opening it. This, however, needs to come from the request that is doing the download, so you can't do this during a redirect. However, ASP.NET offers Response.TransmitFile for this purpose. For example (assuming you aren't using MVC, which has other preferred options):

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=FileName.pdf");
Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
Response.End();
```

If You Are try to open then the file in Api Convert Stream to BytesArray and then Fill the content

```
            HttpResponseMessage result = null;
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(path);
            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
            stream.Close();           
            result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "FileName.pdf";
```