# Spring REST call displays JSON in the browser -- is there a way I can also allow the user to download the file?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I have a basic REST call

```
/**
 * REST CALL
 * @return
 */
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public List<Template> getTemplatesJson(){
    logger.info("GET all computers- /computers/ -- content type = application/json");
    return computerService.retrieveAllComputers();
}
```

When I go to the URL I see the JSON in the browser. We also would like our users to be able to download the JSON as a file (used for importing later on).

Is there an easy way I can do that with this endpoint or do I need to create a brand new endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Content-Disposition` header to indicate to the browser that the content should be downloaded as an attachment instead of being displayed.

1. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012437/uses-of-content-disposition-in-an-http-response-header) on Content-Disposition
2. [Wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) about Content-Disposition

Here's what your code might end up looking like:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public List<Template> getTemplatesJson(HttpServletResponse response) {
    logger.info("GET all computers- /computers/ -- content type = application/json");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=templates.json");
    return computerService.retrieveAllComputers();
}
```