# web.py:How to make a Hyperlink download a file

Tags: python, web.py

I try this `<a href='./number.xls'>download</a>`,but it didn't work. I know that links get different in web.py, but I just want to know how to click the link and download a file just like we used to do in a static environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store those files in the `static` directory along with your web.py application. Then use `<a href='static/number.xls'>download</a>`.

Comment: It helps, but does that mean I have to put all my files which will be downloaded in the static directory?

Comment: That would be the best solution I think. You can also create your own class linked with a specific URL that reads some file and retrieves the content, but this will decrease your app speed since web.py is in the middle. Using the `static` directory, the web server will acceed those files without web.py processing.

Answer (score 0):

This should work find like you have it.

download is the proper syntax for this operation. Maybe try setting the target from self/blank to new window.

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'just like we used to do in a static enviroment', do you mean you're generating the `number.xls` file dynamically? Try setting the Content Disposition header if you are

[Uses of content-disposition in an HTTP response header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012437/uses-of-content-disposition-in-an-http-response-header)

Comment: Not that complicated, and the static directory solved my problem. Thanks all the same.