# How to get the filename from all URLS JAVA

Tags: java, string, parsing, url

What is the best way of getting the file name in a URL using JAVA?
For example if i have https://www.example.com/notes/infortmation.html
I need to pull out information.html section (the file name) from the URL. I need this to work for all URLs. (they won't all be html files)

Comment: Not all urls have filenames. For example, `https://www.example.com/`.

Comment: You could try using `URL#getFile` or `URL#getPath` and then use `substring` to get the content after the last `/`...but honestly, you should just try something...

Comment: Also, you might check for a [Content-Disposition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012437/uses-of-content-disposition-in-an-http-response-header) header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly you have a web address and what the last part of the address. If that is the question you can do that using the following:

```
String add = "https://www.example.com/notes/infortmation.html"; 
String fileName = add.substring(add.lastIndexOf("/")+1) ;
System.out.println(fileName);
```

This will print: 
    information.html
However, as mentioned in the comments not all web addresses have a filename.html or filename.php, etc. Make sure to check if all the addresses that you are parsing have this characteristics otherwise the above method will not get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

String fileName = url.substring( url.lastIndexOf('/')+1, url.length() );

Be aware of this kind of urls  https://www.example.com