# If Content-disposition is not safe to use, what can we use instead?

Tags: httpresponse, content-disposition

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012437/uses-of-content-disposition-in-an-http-response-header) that using content-disposition  has security issues and is not part of the http standard. If content-disposition, what can we use instead?

I've also searched the list of all [response fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) categorized whether it is part of the standard or not and I've not seen a response field that can be used to replace content-disposition.

Comment: If you need it, you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the information about not being a standard is incorrect - see https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6266.html and http://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml (note that Wikipedia is entirely irrelevant with respect to this).