# Fetching the pdf file from database in php

Tags: php

I am getting an error to fetch the pdf file from the database.Below mentioned is my code,please review my code and give me your valuable suggestion.And it's showing output as failed to open the document.Please help me.

```
<?php
    $server = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $db = 'upload';

// Connect to Database
    $connection = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass) or die ("Could not connect to server ... \n" . mysql_error ());
    mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Could not connect to database ... \n" . mysql_error ());
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
    $file=  'SELECT `name`,`size`, `created`,`data` FROM `upload`';
    $result = mysql_query($file);

    if($d = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $file = $d['name'];
        header('Content-type: application/pdf');
        header("Content-Disposition: inline; name=".$row['name']);
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Content-Length: ' . size($file));
        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
        header("Location: $file");
        @readfile($file);
    }
    else{
        echo'No file with the specified ID exists';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue that I see is the single "=" in your if statement.  '=' is for assignment and '==' is for comparison.

Try changing

```
if($d = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

to

```
if($d == mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

EDIT: However, I don't think that will quite work either.  I would try

```
$d = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if ($d === true)
```

Comment: Undefined variable: d in select.php on line 14. I am getting error like this please help me.

Comment: Did you try my second solution? That should assign/define $d.

Comment: Another way you could check for a result would be    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)

Comment: It showing like this."Failed to load PDF document ".

Comment: I'm thinking that you query is failing.  Try $file=  "SELECT * FROM upload WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1";  To debug this I would take the if statement out to make sure the query is working.  Once you are sure the query works then put the if statement back in.

Comment: Thank you, I got output.

Comment: how  to display ppt from db?

Comment: This code only display pdf file. I want to display ppt.

Comment: It should basically be the same code for any file.  However, you will want to output the proper mime type.  For ppt you will probably want to change:

Comment: header('Content-type: application/pdf');  to header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-powerpoint');

Comment: I had to change, but that file has downloading.

Comment: That action is determined by the Content-Disposition header and the browser.  For more info on that check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012437/uses-of-content-disposition-in-an-http-response-header

Answer (score 0):

```
if($result) {
        // Make sure the result is valid
              if($result->num_rows == 1) {

                 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                 header('Content-type: application/pdf');
                 header("Content-Disposition: inline; name=".$row['name']);
                 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                 header("Content-Length: ". $row['size']);
                 header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
            // Print data
                @readfile($row['data']);
                 echo $row['data'];
               }
                else {
                        echo 'Error! No image exists with that ID.';
                }
```