# ASP.Net :couldn't display pdf file new tab in browser

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I have encountered PDF file in web form(.aspx).When I running the page usually display open/save dialog box pdf file.Actually,When I click link,I want to display pdf format in new tab in browser. What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have to fiddle with the "Content-Disposition" of the response header.

This SO post will be a better guide rather than me copy and paste everything.
[Content-Disposition:What are the differences between “inline” and “attachment”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395151/content-dispositionwhat-are-the-differences-between-inline-and-attachment)

UPDATE:
After reading your post again, I think I haven't address your question fully.

For the PDF to be displayed in a new tab/window, the hyperlink that links to the aspx that generates the PDF needs to target to a "_blank" or another target name. E.g.

```
<a href="some.aspx?some=query" target="_blank" ...>Link text</a>
```

You will the have to work on the response header as mentioned above.