# Set Page Title for a PDF inside the Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, pdf, page-title, filecontentresult

I have an action that displays a pdf

```
public ActionResult MyPdf()
{
    var response = pdfService.MyPdf(new PdfRequest() { SiteId = siteSession.ActiveSiteId });

    return File(response.Pdf, "application/pdf");
}
```

The service opens a PDF, fills out the form using data from the database, and then passes back a container class.  `response.Pdf` is a `byte[]`.

What I want to do is set the page title used by the browser when the PDF is opened.  Currently, `File(response.Pdf, "application/pdf");` will allow my browser (chrome) to display the pdf.

If I change it to `File(response.Pdf, "application/pdf", "My PDF File Name");`, the pdf is not displayed but is automatically downloaded.

My action has no View defined.  How can I show the PDF in the browser without forcing the download and set the page title from my action method?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with mvc, but to get the pdf to display in the browser and specify a filename you usually set the content disposition header to inline (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395151/content-dispositionwhat-are-the-differences-between-inline-and-attachment). Is `File` your own type or is it included in the framework?

Comment: It is included in the framework.

Comment: Sorry, if you don't mind could you give me the fully qualified name. I'm looking for it but I can't find it (maybe because I have MVC3 installed and not MVC2)?

Comment: [`FileContentResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult.aspx)