# IE 9 Wants to Download Image Instead of Display

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html4

I'm making a `get` request similar to `http://localhost:5050/Resource/Fetch/38763905-7e26-4ca0-adf5-2cb803b6bf75/53` to call my controller action that takes a GUID and a resolution number.  It does some magic on the server side with some images and returns to my view an image.  In all browsers the image displays on the page just fine but with IE9 I'm prompted to download or save the image.

Here is my jQuery line:

```
$('#myImage').attr("src", Ugc.Index.ProjectSubmit.ImageFetch + "/38763905-7e26-4ca0-adf5-2cb803b6bf75/53");
```

Thank you for your help,

Aaron

Comment: Seems that IE is not sending an ajax request. Can you check with fiddler? Any javascript errors on the page?

Comment: No, no errors according to IE's dev tools' console or in Fiddler.

Comment: BTW, no AJAX.  Just passive jQuery URL placed into <img>'s "src" attribute.  Maybe I need AJAX?

Comment: Is it because of the extension? Maybe IE is confused because it doesn't understand what it is.

Comment: Dismissile, now there's an idea.  I'll try that.

Comment: Ah sorry, no ajax needed here. I do it exactly like you and it works for me at least for IE 8. Extension is not the problem. Maybe the returned ContentType is wrong? Can you check that?

Comment: Post your code for your `ImageFetch` action - the issue will be in there.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to specify **content dispositon = inline** header if you are sending this file by yourself by writing it to response.

See : [Content-Disposition:What are the differences between "inline" and "attachment"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395151/content-dispositionwhat-are-the-differences-between-inline-and-attachment)

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, when you write the image to the Response, set content type to "image/jpg" or whatever format your image is in. If that doesn't help, can you post the piece of code that outputs the image?